# How do I amend roles for the Administer Users by Role module?

Tags: users

I'm using the [Administer Users by Role](https://www.drupal.org/project/administerusersbyrole) module. I have a role set up as *Publisher* which has all the boxes ticked under the "*Administer Users by Role*" option (under People/Permissions as shown in the picture below):

[image]

The Publisher can create/edit users. I have created a menu option for the Publisher user, which has a path of admin/people/edit so they can see all the users, and add a user too.

My problem is that when the Publisher amends or creates an account, they cannot see the Role of the user they are amending, so they only have the option to create an authenticated user or amend an existing user, they cannot amend the **role** for that user.

However, as administrator I am able to see the role option and set accordingly.

Can anyone advise how to allow this for my Publisher role?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible scenario to implement what you're looking for is like so:

- Use the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module to allow a Publisher (any other roles also?) to flag users to indicate that they "*want to amend the role for that user*" (say you label such flag as "*Amend User*").
- Then use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module to react to (Rules Event) "A user gets flagged with the *Amend User* flag", combined with a Rules Action to "grant a role to the flagged user" (which could be multiple roles also if needed).
- If you need more granularity to be able to do so for multiple roles (like role A for user X, role B for user Y and role A and B for user Z), then just use multiple flags (1 for each role individually).

True, this would require 2 more modules, but pretty sure you'll find lots of other use-cases for these amazing modules (which should be part of pretty much every Drupal site).